# Which wysiwyg editor in Drupal will give me most control over markup?

Tags: javascript, drupal, wysiwyg

At the moment I'm using the wysiwyg module for Drupal with tiny_mce. However, it keeps inserting all kinds of superfluous spans and other trash elements in my markup. I want to use wysiwyg mostly for semantic markup with css classes, any inline styles are a problem, because I have to clean up my html by hand - sort of defies the purpose of having a wysiwyg editor altogether. What other wysiwyg editor should I try, which will behave more sensibly?

Comment: i am a fan of what is now known as CKEditor.  I do not know how it integrates with drupal.

Comment: @Andrey: it can be integrated with the WYSIWYG API module

Comment: Also it's have standalone module cKEditor. Most recommend plugin from my experience of using wysiwygs. Standalone module has more settings than universal WYSIWYG module.

Comment: You say that hand-editting markup defeats the purpose of a WYSIWYG editor. I would say that wanting tight control over your markup defeats the purpose of a WYSIWYG editor. If you're that worried about it, write the markup yourself.

Comment: I would use the WYSIWYG API module and experiment with all the editors that are able to plug into that. Some are better then others but I haven't found any that are truly great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wanted to go with CKEditor myself but after trying to get rid of that adding breaks and spaces everywhere stuff I had to revert to plain text input.

I am currently considering [markitup!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com), which you may want to investigate as well.
I am hopeful as I have good experiences with it on WP but I didn't get to try it on Drupal just yet.

Answer (score 3):

[WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/), available via the [WYSIWYG API](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), is not the fanciest editor, but it does produce XHTML markup.

[BUEditor](http://ufku.com/drupal/bueditor) integrated via the [BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/bueditor) module, is an easily extensible system that allows you to easily define buttons and associated markup. It is a favorite of a markup-obsessed colleague of mine, so I imagine it does a good job.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience ck editor is a very good solution.
The only problem i have seen it have is drop a 
 instead of leaving a box blank
It has paste plain text and paste from word features that prevent extra markup from being dropped in

When working with a cms i think what is important usually is not how well you can enter markup, as a developer you can usually just use a text area and drop html, but how the editors will enter content.

Ck editor usually produces very clean results, as long as direct pasting from Word does not take place

As people have helped me out in the comments, there are two ways to integrate it with Drupal

WYSIWYG API module, and standalone module cKEditor

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest BUEditor, you can configure all buttons and thus control the output

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have yet to find an editor that doesn't try to mess with your code in one way or another. In Drupal, I've tried TinyMCE, FCKEditor, and CKEditor. In non-Drupal projects I've used Ephox EditLive and the YUI 2 Rich Text Editor. All of them try to "fix" or autoformat your code in one way or another, and to that end they are all frustrating. Of that group, Ephox EditLive is the worst offender, and ironically it's the only one that isn't free.

I've resigned myself to plain text editing in Drupal whenever there's a slight chance I may need to control the underlying HTML. My WYSIWYG editor is off by default; I whitelist pages in as needed. It's tedious, but for me it's better than playing tug-of-war with the WYSIWYG for control.